# Return a list of records where a field value is contained in a range of values

Tags: c#, linq

using Linq c# (trying to!)

I am also using sql lite.

I query 1 table to get a range of values for 1 field.

I then query a second table to return records that match all the values in the 1st query.

This is my code:

```
var query = from jobRecord in DB.Connector.Table<InformedWorkerModel.JobRecord>()
                where jobRecord.CustomerRef == customerRef
                select jobRecord.AddressRef;



var addresses = (from address in DB.Connector.Table<InformedWorkerModel.Tables.Address>()
           where query.Contains(address.AddressRef)
           select address);
```

When I try to 'look' at my addresses result (expecting to see rows (or not) of matching address I get the error:

No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

This is my poco class:

```
[Table("Address")]
public class Address
{
    public Address()
    {

    }
    [Column("AddressId")]
    [PrimaryKey]
    [NotNull]
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string AddressRef { get; set; }
    public string Add1 { get; set; }

    public string Add2 { get; set; }
    public string Add3 { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }

}

[Table("JobRecord")]
public class JobRecord
{
    public JobRecord()
    {

    }
    [SQLite.PrimaryKey, SQLite.AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    [Ignore]
    public DateTime LastStatusChanged { get; set; }
    public enMethodOfPayment BookFeePaidBy { get; set; }
    public float PriorityFee { get; set; }
    public string AddressRef { get; set; }
    public string PassCode { get; set; }
    public string TermsAndConditions { get; set; }
    public string WorkItemsRef { get; set; }
    public double BookingFeePaid { get; set; }
    public bool UnderWarrantry { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public float BookingFee { get; set; }
    public string Base64Signature { get; set; }
    public string Attachments { get; set; }
    public string BookedInBy { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public string CustomerRef { get; set; }      
    public string SpecialNotes { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateReq { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOE { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCompleted { get; set; }
    public string JobRef { get; set; }
    public int ClientKey { get; set; }
    public string Other { get; set; }
    public string ProductDetails { get; set; }
    public string ServiceReq { get; set; }
    public string JobStatus { get; set; }
    public enMethodOfPayment PaidBy { get; set; }
    public bool OptInForSMSAuthorisations { get; set; }
    public string ImageToken { get; set; }
    public string PriortyType { get; set; }


    public int? ServerId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is `AddressId`?

Comment: @SLaks hi. That is the primary key in my table

Comment: Can you also show the `JobRecord` class?

Comment: sure 1 second  :)

Comment: Perhaps if you give JobRecord a parameterless constructor  (and any other class properties you are using). It is possible that the error is occurring in your first statement because that appears to return an IEnumerable so you wouldn't know about it until the data is actually accessed when you are calling query.Contains

Comment: and what about `enMethodOfPayment` :) ?

Comment: try removing the where clause and see if in that case addresses  has parmaters

Comment: @people will try/reply in sequence :) thanks

Comment: @pieperu tried but it made no difference but good thinking

Comment: @Oliver hi, this is just a enum value but should have no bearing on this question?

Comment: @AndrewSimpson is there more than one `JobRecord` class?  Your namespaces are different: `InformedWorkerModel.X` and `InformedWorkerModel.Tables.X`

Comment: @Shachaf.Gortler yes you are correct it is the where clause that is causing the issue (thanks) so now the question is why does my contains clause not work please?

Comment: @oliver let me make sure it is not a copy and paste issue

Comment: @Oliver no just 1 jobrecord class. the namespace is different but correctly referenced

Comment: I know it looks strange but add a parameter less constructor to `JobRecord`. `public JobRecord() { }`

Comment: @dotctor I already had but no joy. updated my question to show this :(

Comment: I get the sense that you're trying to 'look' at `addresses` by setting a breakpoint and then inspecting the contents of the variable. This is a guess. If so, try changing your code to `var addresses = (your query here).ToList()`. After that change, does `addresses` contain what you expect? (Maybe the debugger is choking.)

Comment: @VinceHorst hi, possibly.. i wil check asap and comment back. thanks for your input much appreciated